# Show that the following maps are (not) ring homomorphisms. Complex Numbers.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, ring-homomorphism

Problem:

Show that the following maps are (not) ring homomorphisms (with or without 1):

$\phi: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}, a +bi \mapsto \left( \begin{array}{rrr}a & b\\ -b & a \\ \end{array}\right)$

$inv: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, a+bi \mapsto (a+bi)^{-1}$

$pot_2 : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, a+bi \mapsto (a+bi)^2$

$\phi_i: \mathbb{R}[X] \to \mathbb{C}, f \mapsto f(i)$ ($i$ being the imaginary number)

Questions:

I would like to know more about how to figure out that these are ring homomorphisms, as i am not really well versed in the complex numbers. Would there be any sort of advice on the matter ? I appreciate any help given.

Comment: well, what are the properties of a ring homomorphism? Knock out each one at a time. For example, $inv$ clearly isn't a ring morphism since it isn't even defined on all complex numbers!

Comment: On the other hand, $\phi_i$ is a ring morphism, with kernel $(x^2+1)$, which indicates that $$\mathbb R[X]/(x^2+1)\sim\mathbb C$$

Comment: What have you tried? You should give more context.

Comment: What i have tried is at least the $pot_2$ one as well as the regular $\phi$, where i did some calculations and transformed the terms back into their respective places. At least thats what i thought. I had no idea how to tackle $inv$ for now. Other than that. Also i do not really know how it's not even defined on all the complex numbers. As essentially i just started learning about the Complex Numbers. For $\phi_i$ i personally have also not really a true idea on what to do, though the hint with the kernel was quite helpful.

Comment: From what i did now, i was showing that $\frac{a}{a^2 + b^2} - \frac{b}{a^2 +b^2}i$ aka $inv$ is only defined on every complex number which $a^2 +b^2 \neq 0$. That cannot be a ring homomorphism already.
For the Matrix it breaks down on the Matrix Multiplication, due to $\phi(a +bi * c + di) = \begin{pmatrix} ac-bd & i(ad+cb) \\ -(i(ad +cb)) & ac-bd \end{pmatrix} \neq \begin{pmatrix} ac+bd & i(ad+cb) \\ -(i(ad +cb)) & ac+bd \end{pmatrix} = \phi(a+bi) * \phi(c+di)$